# Delayed insulation failure of DC barrel jack

Tags: connector, insulation

Recently I had to replace a male DC barrel jack that connected a string of LEDs to a driver. Unconnected, I measured 100 VDC out of the driver.  The male jack I salvaged from an old 12 VDC power supply.

I made sure the current out of the driver is lower than the current the old power supply was rated for, but there was no way to find out what the jack´s voltage rating is. I replaced the jack and ran the LEDs for a couple of hours, after which everything ran normally and the jack didn't feel warm at all.

What I am worried about is that the jack is being used at a voltage higher than it was originally intended for. It ran without any issues for a couple of hours. If insulation were insufficient, I would expect it to fail rapidly.

- How long does insulation take to fail when used over its rated voltage?
- How is it expected to fail?
- Should I be worried about my replacement causing a fire or other adverse effects?

Comment: If you unplug in AC first  and that will be infrequently, there is no chance of arcing from inductance and plug in AC last, no worry of over current. If you plan on frequent connections, a 4 pin molex will be better with wider separation on outside pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I picked a somewhat random example of a DC (usually low-voltage) barrel jack.  It's datasheet is here:

[Barrel Jack](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/pj1-022-smt-tr.pdf)

The relevant specification is here:

[image: Voltage Specification]

So in this case, the device is rated to withstand 500 VAC for 1 minute.  How long would it last at 100V?  It's anyone's guess but generally dielectric breakdown occurs over time and will eventually fail.

In your case, I'd err on the side of caution and use a connector that is rated for 100V instead of 12V.

Answer (score 3):

It's not insulation failure that will be the first problem, it will be arcing between contacts. Most insulation is rated for 100's of volts. But really it's the conductor spacing that can be a problem.
Below is at table of IEC regulations. For 100V the spacing needs to be 0.2mm between any conductor. So between the plus and minus terminals of the DC barrel jack the distance needs to be specified for the greatest voltage. So if you think you need 1000V then make sure the spacing is right.

[image]
Source: [https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?p=AONE&u=googlescholar&id=GALE|A111490273&v=2.1&it=r&sid=AONE&asid=81d5a14e](https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?p=AONE&u=googlescholar&id=GALE%7CA111490273&v=2.1&it=r&sid=AONE&asid=81d5a14e)

Secondly the DC barrel jack should have a datasheet and it should have the highest voltage allowed, so that can be checked also, make sure the jack will be specified for the greatest voltage.

Insulation does breakdown, but it should show the rating on the insulation of the cable and if you use a jack it should have a voltage rating which it (should have) been tested to.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a professional point of view, I would advise you not to use the adapter since you do not know the rated voltage. DC currents are easier to catch fire since the voltage is constant (AC voltage from the other hand would be safer.) Especially at 100V, something could go wrong.

As a hobbyist, I would tell you that since it does not get hot in a hot day (not a casual winter, so test it at summer) it is good to go, and the insulation will last, since it did not fail already - but do not leave the light on when you are away. 100V is a lot.

I personally use a lot of patent stuff in my garage. I always unplug them when I am away.

Many live examples can be seen at solar panels: https://news.dualsun.com/installation-maintenance/solar-panel-fire/

It says: *For instance, the incorrect seaming of connectors may generate electrical arcing, meaning a release of considerable heat. If this occurs, it may cause overheating and a fire.*

Answer (score 0):

None of the insulation questions matter much, because barrel jacks are not meant to be used with unsafe voltages. 48V is the maximum: they have no regulatory approvals for anything more and are not designed to prevent you from coming in contact with dangerous potentials. The use of such a jack exposes you and other users of your contraption to gratuitous hazards.

So that’s pretty much all there’s to it – discussing whether the jack’s insulation is sufficient etc. is moot and detracts from the central safety concern.

Use a connector that’s finger-safe and rated for the highest voltage and current it’ll carry – the two conditions don’t have to be concurrent, the ratings still apply.

Comment: I also read 48 V was the maximum but the lamp came from the factory with a DC jack of the same physical characteristics. I find it quite weird.